# How to access the content of a void pointer inside a struct pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct, void-pointers

I have a struct pointer, that points to a struct that has a void pointer as it member, and I need to access the value of this member.

This is the struct with the void pointer I need access

```
typedef struct {
    void *content;
} st_data;
```

This is the function to create the struct, it returns a pointer to the struct

```
st_data *create_struct(void *content)
{
    st_data *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(st_data));
    new->content = content;
    return new;
}
```

I cant find the right syntax to print the value of the void pointer.

```
int main()
{
    int *number;
    *number = 10;
    st_data *new_struct = create_struct(number);
    
// just want to print the value of the void pointer 
    printf("%d\n", *(int *)new_struct->content);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int *number;` is an uninitialised pointer, which you then de-reference, leading to undefined behaviour. You probably want `int number = 10; ... create_struct(&number)` or similar.

Comment: `void *` pointers don't have "content" because they can't be dereferenced.  They can point to "something" but have no information about what that "something" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare a pointer to an int, but it doesn't point to anything:

```
int *number; // Doesn't point to anything
```

You then de-reference this pointer, which leads to undefined behaviour:

```
*number = 10; // BUG - undefined behaviour
```

You need to actually define a variable to store your number 10, and pass the address of that to your 'constructor':

```
int number = 10;
st_data *new_struct = create_struct(&number);
```

Note that while this will work in your simple example, if your 'new_struct' structure outlived this function you'd have a problem, since the 'content' pointer points to something allocated on the stack, which would disappear if the function exited.

Answer (score 3):

@pmacfarlane's comment is more important (IMHO), but this will print the value of the pointer (as opposed to what it points *to*, as your code does):

```
printf("%p\n", new_struct->content);
```

Comment: Actually, I want to print the integer. By sending the integer address to the function `int number = 10;` `st_data *new_struct = create_struct(&number);` I am now able to get the integer with `printf("%d\n", *(int *)new_struct->content);`